# C++ getting highest test score and using pointers

Tags: c++

created a program to prompt the user to enter test scores and find the average, highest, and sort the test score. I am having problems  I cant seem to get the higest test scores from the function I made and when I created the sorting test score function the program crashes. Can someone look at my functions and see where my problem is, I seem to get the average test score to show.

```
double getAverage(double*, int);
double gethighest(double*, int);
double getlowest(double*, int);
void arrayAscending(double*, int);

int main()
{
    // Variable declarations
    double *testScores; // Dynamically allocate an array of test scores
    double average, highest, lowest;     
    int numTests;       // Number of test scores
    int count;          // Counter variable

                        // Get the number of tests
    cout << "How many tests do you wish to process? ";
    cin >> numTests;

    // Verify input is not a negative number
    while (numTests <= 0)
    {
        // Get input again.
        cout << "Please enter a positive number:  ";
        cin >> numTests;
    }

    // Dynamically allocate an array large enough to hold the test scores
    testScores = new double[numTests];

    // Get the specified number of test scores
    cout << "Enter the test scores below.\n";
    for (count = 0; count < numTests; count++)
    {
        cout << "Test " << (count + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> *(testScores + count);

        // Verify input is not a negative number
        while (*(testScores + count) < 0)
        {
            // Get input again.
            cout << "Please enter a valid test score.\n";
            cin >> *(testScores + count);
        }
    }

    // Calculate the average test score
    average = getAverage(testScores, numTests);
    highest = gethighest(testScores, numTests);
    lowest = getlowest(testScores, numTests);
    // Display the results.

    arrayAscending(testScores, numTests);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The average of those scores is:  " << average << endl;

    cout << "The higest of those scores is: " << highest << endl;
    cout << "The lowest of those scores is: " << lowest << endl;

    // Free dynamically allocated memory
    delete[] testScores;
    testScores = 0;     // Make testScores point to null
    return 0;
}

//function getAverage - calculates the average of the test scores
double getAverage(double* scores, int num)
{
    double avg;
    double total = 0.0;
    for (int count = 0; count < num; count++)
    {
        total += scores[count];
    }
    avg = total / num;
    return avg;
}

double gethighest(double* scores, int num)
{
    double highnum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (scores[i] > highnum)
            highnum = scores[i];

    }
    return highnum;
}

double getlowest(double* scores, int num)
{
    double lowestnum = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (scores[i] < lowestnum)
            lowestnum = scores[i];
    }
    return lowestnum;
}

void arrayAscending(double *array, int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex;
    double minElem;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minElem = array[startScan];
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)

        {
            if ((array[index]) < minElem)
            {
                minElem = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
        array[startScan] = minElem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void arrayAscending(double *[], int);
```

should be

```
void arrayAscending(double *, int);
```

You are sorting an array of doubles, not an array of pointers to double.

Also,

```
double *minElem;
```

is used later without any memory being allocated for it. Again, you probably need just

```
double minElem;
```

and not a pointer.

If you don't need to use pointers, then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and algorithms from the standard library like [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: thanks for your help can you look at my updated code ran it no errors but array doesn't show up @vsoftco

Comment: @MikeShasaco Works fine on my side. Run it from a terminal and you'll see the result. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec36b87e770cb441).

Comment: I see the results of the lowest, highest, and average but I don't see the results from the arrayAscending

Comment: @MikeShasaco That's because you don't display the sorted array anywhere. Add `for(int i = 0; i < numTests; ++i) cout << testScores[i] << ' ';` before `delete[] testScores;` and you'll see it.